# How to raise a form error in \CRM_Core_Form::postProcess()

Tags: mailing, quickform

I have a class with a signature:

class CRM_Contact_Form_Task_FooPdf extends CRM_Contact_Form_Task {

What generates a PDF. During the PDF generation, there might be an error. This task also uses the standard mail template:

```
public function buildQuickForm() {
  // Add message templates.
  CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing::commonCompose($this);
  CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addScriptFile('civicrm', 'templates/CRM/Contact/Form/Task/EmailCommon.js', 0, 'html-header');
  $this->addDefaultButtons(ts('Continue'), 'done', 'cancel');
}
```

It works totally fine. It shows up among the actions on a search form, when I select it, the template UI shows up, and i have access to the data. The only issue is that during the PDF generation, sometimes I need to raise an error, which is not a fatal error, but something that the user must correct himself.
At the PDF generation, i am in the \CRM_Core_Form::postProcess() phase. Can I set a form error and re-display the form with the submitted values?

Issuing this (and of course skip to stream the PDF) does not work, as I am redirected simply to the main admin page of CiviCRM, the form is not re-generated:

```
$this->setElementError('text_message', 'moo');
```

But I guess it's because i am already at the postprocessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that `postProcess` runs too late. Consider the [conventional request lifecycle for HTML_QuickForm/CRM_Core_Form](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/QuickForm+Reference#QuickFormReference-RequestLifecycle):

[image: Overall Request Lifecycle in CRM_Core_Form]

At the end of the `Validate` phase, it makes a major decision about whether to rerender the form with errors. However, the `postProcess` function is part of the `Process` phase which should only run on valid forms.

The conventional way to set a validation error in `HTML_QuickForm` is to register a validation function. For example, in [`CRM_Group_Form_Edit::buildQuickForm()`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.7.10/CRM/Group/Form/Edit.php#L296), note how it calls `addFormRule(...)` (and how the `static function formRule()` conditionally returns an array of errors). This runs at the correct time.

For mitigations, you might consider:

- Add some checks in the validation phase to predict whether the error condition will arise. (Ex: If the issue is a missing dependency or inadequate RAM, then validate the dependency or RAM beforehand.)
- Report the error via `CRM_Core_Error::fatal()`, `throw new Exception()`, or `CRM_Core_Error::statusBounce()`.
- Don't rely on `HTML_QuickForm` as the main form processor. Implement client-side logic with Javascript and AJAX callbacks.
- (Evil but possibly working) Do the heavy lifting during the validate phase. (This will, e.g., make it hard for third-parties to hook into the form... but it may work...)
- (Evil but possibly working) Dig into the mechanics of the `CRM_Core_Form` lifecycle and figure out a way to short-circuit/cross-wire the phases for your controller.

Comment: "Do the heavy lifting during the validate phase." - I will pick this approach, I'll generate the PDF at validation phase and serve it via HTTP at submission.